# Empty Space at top of new Page after Section Add New Page After enable

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Report have 2 sections, 1st and 2nd. 
I have added New Page After on both sections so that 2nd section is always on new page and after 2nd section 1st section again on new page. Every thing is good but, on 2nd page there is a empty space.

I expect to not have that empty space.

[Image 1 normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvz9E.png)

[Image 2 next page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGiTn.png)